# Purging "xfce4-notifyd" purges "ubuntustudio-desktop" with it. Why? How to avoid this if possible

Tags: apt

I want to remove `xfce4-notifyd`; this package makes the notifications look different and removing it restores the normal notifications. I tried `sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd` but it says it will remove both; `xfce4-notifyd` and `ubuntustudio-desktop`. Why does this happen and how to avoid this if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `xfce4-notifyd` is the standard notification daemon for Ubuntu Studio (has XFCE desktop). However if you want to remove/replace it, you can do so:

- Either `sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd` and let it remove `ubuntustudio-desktop` as it is a meta package (no harm, it's an empty package). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages
- Or just disable `xfce4-notifyd` service:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disable
  ```

  Then kill already running one:

  ```
  sudo pkill xfce4-notifyd
  ```

  To re-enable it, rename it back:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disable /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service
  ```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :D ...Just one more question. The command that disables xfce4-notifyd, it moves just moves it to another directory right? I mean if I want to re-enable it I can move it back?

Comment: @MinaMichael, yep. Even it not really moved it, It just rename it by adding `.disable` to the end of name. Because DBus system looks only for files with `.service` extension. Yes, you can put back whenever you want. updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be avoided.:

`xfce4-notifyd` is a dependency for `ubuntustudio-desktop`.

Refer: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntustudio-desktop

When a dependancy is being removed dependent is also being removed.